# A nonstatic member reference error in Array using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I am a beginner in programming C++ and I'm learning all about classes and objects right now. For practice, I created a class called Employee and added some members in it. But I noticed that the record array is giving me an error stating a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object. This only happens whenever I create an array in Employee class. But when I called it in my constructor `Employee()`, it is not highlighted as an error, as well as when I tried initializing it as a global variable, or even a local variable in my main.cpp(this is where `main()` is located). Kindly give advice or even better solution for this.

```
   #pragma once
   #include<string>
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class Employee
   {
   private:
   int recordSize = 100;
   int fieldSize = 4;
   string record[recordSize][fieldSize];

   public:
   Employee();
   ~Employee();

   };
```

main.cpp:

```
   #include "Employee.h"
   #include<string>
   #include<iostream>
   #include<iomanip>
   #include<fstream>
   using namespace std;

   Employee::Employee() {
      ifstream inFile;
      inFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt");

      for (int index = 0; index < recordSize; index++) {
          for (int index2 = 0; index2 < fieldSize; index2++) {
             inFile >> record[recordSize][fieldSize];
             }
           }
          }

   Employee::~Employee()
   {
   }
```

I also include content of employee-info.txt

```
 ID           Firstname            Lastname                 Sales
 1                Bruno                Mars             120000.00
 2               Lebron               James             150000.00
```

Comment: *`using namespace std;`* – never in a header file. – *`C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt`* – content?

Comment: `string record[recordSize][fieldSize];` -- This is not valid C++.  It is the same error if you did this: `int main() { int recordSize = 100; std::string record[recordSize];}`,  So are your arrays fixed size, or can they vary in size at runtime?  The answer depends on what your intent is here.

Comment: You need to read some more about arrays in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: What you want to achive with your code? Array of Strings?

Comment: `inFile >> record[recordSize][fieldSize];` should be `inFile >> record[index][index2];`

Comment: @Swordfish - I now include the content of the employee-info.txt in my post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - arrays are fixed size.

Comment: @wuarmin - I wanted to try to create a mini-record of all employees via a text file. I included the contents of the file in my post just now.

Comment: @mch - yes, my mistake on that part, I changed it just now.

Comment: @Swordfish I don't think you should make these kind of edits to the original code: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). You're removing (from your point of view) unnecessary ctors/dtors and `using namespace std;`. While this might look better to you, I think you should leave the OP's code as it was posted originally (minus formatting issues etc.).

Comment: @andreee you are probably right. i rolled it back to the original bs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `recordSize` and `fieldSize` need to be both `static` and `const` (or `constexpr`) to be used as dimensions of `std::string record` 2D array.

They need to be `const` because the array bound should be an integer constant.

They need to be `static` because the `record` array is not allowed to have different sizes for different instantiations of `Employee` class.

If you want the 2D array to be able to hold different sizes in different instantiations of `Employee` class, you should go for an `std::vector` of `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: This one answered my problem. Great info and advice. I still need to practice more tho. long way to go.

Comment: In fact, I would always recommend going for `std::vector` *first*, and then think about changing to `std::array` or a raw array if you find there is a need to.  You *certainly* want a std::vector of records; for each individual record you might well prefer a struct/class.

Answer (score -1):

The sizes need to be constexpr when used to define array sizes

```
static constexpr int recordSize = 100;
static constexpr int fieldSize = 4;
string record[recordSize][fieldSize];
```